# KIK: How do I programatically open the sidebar?

Tags: kik

Is there a way for me to open the sidebar using one of the buttons on my HTML5 app? I know KIK displays that "3 vertical dots" button/slider on the left for users to open the sidebar, but can I still trigger that using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

There are no APIs to open the sidebar. Only the user can do so